# Спарсить HTML и сложить значения строк

Tags: php, javascript, html

Имеется кусок сайта.

```
<table id="trades">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>SUMM</th>
            <th>PROMO-CODE</th>
            <th>STEAMID</th>
            <th>DATE</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="11499">
            <td>$5.01</td>
            <td>AEST01A</td>
            <td>11499</td>
            <td>2017-05-06 15:12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="11504">
            <td>$0.56</td>
            <td>AEST01A</td>
            <td>11504</td>
            <td>2017-05-07 19:45</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

как мне спарсить только строки где есть $ и дальше сложить эти значения в переменной?

p.s id= может быть любой. кол.во  тоже может быть большим

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через регулярные выражения ищем данные:

```
preg_match_all('/\$([\d]+\.[\d]+)/iu', $html, $matches);
```

Далее складываем данные из переменной $matches:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($matches[1] as $a) $sum += $a;
```

Указанная выше регулярка будет работать с вашим HTML, но для более стабильной работы желательно проводить поиск по более строгому условию.